# How i parse with lxml a result page with form?

Tags: python, lxml

I try to parse a secondary page with form . I use example code source from this link :
http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/24/lxmlhtml/
On my test i use this url: http://www.infofer.ro/ 
Like on example , I use this values :

```
>>> pprint(form.form_values())
[('cboData', '8/30/2010'),
 ('txtPlecare', 'Bucuresti Nord'),
 ('txtSosire', 'Constanta'),
 ('tip', 'GO'),
 ('lng', '1')]
```

The result is take it with this :

```
result = parse(submit_form(form)).getroot()
```

This is another page with another form .
I try something like this :

```
>>> page2=parse(result).getroot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 661, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2706, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:49945)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1525, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72026)
TypeError: cannot parse from 'HtmlElement'
```

How i parse the form from secondary page ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getroot` method does not give you another "page", but an instance of `lxml.html.HtmlElement`.

There is no need (and no way) to `parse` this once more, you already have everything you need packed into the `result` variable.